# excel vba dictionary vlookup

Tags: excel, performance, dictionary, mapping

My code need more than one hours to complete for 3500 rows but I need to work for more than 40000 rows data.

I am looking for alternatives to my code by using dictionary, with improved performance within the context of interest.

Could anyone help me?

```
Sub StripRow2Node()
'Read the Strip Design table
With Sheets("Design-Moment")
    Sheets("Design-Moment").Activate
    LastR1 = .Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DM_arr = .Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastR1, 7)) 'Col 1 to Col 7
    DM_count = UBound(DM_arr, 1)
End With
'Read the x and y coordinations and thickness of a node in node design
With Sheets("Design-Shear")
    Sheets("Design-Shear").Activate
    LastR2 = .Range("B" & Cells.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    DS_arr = .Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(LastR2, 5)) 'Col 4 to Col 5
    SX_arr = .Range(Cells(1, 26), Cells(LastR2, 27))
    SY_arr = .Range(Cells(1, 30), Cells(LastR2, 31))
    DS_count = UBound(DS_arr, 1)
End With

'** Find correponding reference row in Design-Moment for nodes**
'Match node to striip station and output row index
For i = 5 To DS_count
    XStrip = SX_arr(i, 1)
    XStation = DS_arr(i, 1)
    YStrip = SY_arr(i, 1)
    YStation = DS_arr(i, 2)
    For j = 5 To DM_count
        If DM_arr(j, 1) = XStrip Then 'X-Strip Name is matched
            If DM_arr(j, 4) >= XStation And DM_arr(j - 1, 4) < XStation Then
                SX_arr(i, 2) = j  'matched row reference for X-strip
            End If
        End If
        If DM_arr(j, 1) = YStrip Then
            If DM_arr(j, 5) <= YStation And DM_arr(j - 1, 5) > YStation Then
                SY_arr(i, 2) = j
            End If
        End If
    Next j
Next i
'Write the matched strip information to node
For i = 5 To LastR2
    With Sheets("Design-Shear")
        .Cells(i, 27) = SX_arr(i, 2)
        .Cells(i, 31) = SY_arr(i, 2)
    End With
Next i
```

End Sub

Answer (score 1):

There are several points to improve:
1. Use qualified references to avoid`.activate` statements
You start off nicely with

```
With Sheets("Design-Shear")
    ...
    DS_arr = .Range(Cells(1, 4), Cells(LastR2, 5)) 'Col 4 to Col 5
```

but fail to make the `Cells` objects refer to the `With` block. Instead use

```
With Sheets("Design-Shear")
    ...
    DS_arr = .Range(.Cells(1, 4), .Cells(LastR2, 5)) 'Col 4 to Col 5
```

Now you do not have to activate the sheet anymore.

2. From the code I have to assume that there is only one possible match returned in this statement:

   `SX_arr(i, 2) = j`

for all `i`; otherwise, the second, third...occurrence would overwrite this value of `j`. If that is indeed the case you can stop looping over `j` once a match is found:

```
SX_arr(i, 2) = j  'matched row reference for X-strip
Exit For
```

Shortcut both `If` statements if `DM_arr(j, 1)` can match `XStrip` or `YStrip`. If these matches are mutually exclusive, use `ElseIf` instead of `If` for the second statement.
Shortcutting the `j`-loop should improve the runtime noticeably. Of course, if you need the *last* matching index (instead of the *first*) then this will not apply.

**edit:**
For a dictionary solution, see for instance the excellent code from Jeeped here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/133664/searching-values-of-range-x-in-range-y

Comment: Is it possible to improve the performance by rewrite the code using "Scripting Dictionary"?

Comment: Hard to tell from your code alone. If values in DM_arr are unique then storing and checking for their existance in a dictionary would reduce the effort from quadratic to near linear. Alternatively, instead of searching sequentially you could still use an array, by sorting it and applying a binary search.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that almost all the time is being used writing back cell-by-cell to the sheet here:

```
'Write the matched strip information to node
For i = 5 To LastR2
    With Sheets("Design-Shear")
        .Cells(i, 27) = SX_arr(i, 2)
        .Cells(i, 31) = SY_arr(i, 2)
    End With
Next i
```

Writing back to Excel is much slower than reading from Excel.
I would suggest switching off screen updating and calculation, accumulating the results (currently X_arr(i, 2) and SY_arr(i, 2)) in separate arrays and then writing the arrays back to a range in a single operation rather than cell-by-cell

Comment: Depends on the number of rows. In fact, one could write back the complete arrays SX_arr and SY_arr as their first column is unchanged. Converting both arrays into 4 and writing back only the Y column arrays wouldn't be that much faster.

Comment: I strongly agree with turning off calculation. Even if there are no formulas that are affected by the data dump, a single volatile formula is recalculating for every value returned to the worksheet.

Comment: @user1016274 - Its 40000 rows so it matters, but you are absolutely right that you could write back the complete SX and SY arrays - I had not spotted that.